# how to get selected value of dropdownlist on nested gridview row command

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can i get selected value of dropdownlist on nested gridview row command.

I have a nested gridview in my page, inside of second gridview i want to use a drop down list for Driver. I am trying to get the selected value for that drop down list but unable to got it in gridview rowcommand. i try button click event also but i am unable to got it.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="dtgNewTrips" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" OnRowDataBound="dtgNewTrips_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="Trips_ID">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="JavaScript:ViewDetails('div<%# Eval(" Trips_ID ") %>');">
                                            <img alt="City" id="imgdiv<%# Eval("Trips_ID") %>" src="Images/Icons/plusicon.png" />
                                        </a>
        <div id="div<%# Eval(" Trips_ID ") %>" style="display: none;">
          <asp:GridView ID="dtgViewDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Trips_ID" CssClass="ChildGrid" ShowHeader="false" OnRowDataBound="dtgViewDetails_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="dtgViewDetails_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <div>
                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                      <tr>
                        <td>Adults:
                          <asp:Label ID="lblTrip_ID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Trips_ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AdultsCount") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>Children:
                          <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ChildrensCount") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>Passenger Comments:
                          <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PassengerComments") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Trip Stops:</td>
                        <td>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TripStops") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>TripStops Comments:
                          <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TripStopsComments") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDriver" runat="server" DataTextField="DriverName" DataValueField="DriversInfo_ID" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                          </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <asp:Button ID="btnAssign" runat="server" Text="Assign To Driver" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>' CommandName="Assign" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <asp:Button ID="btnAssignToAll" runat="server" OnClick="btnAssignToAll_Click" Text="Notify All Drivers" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
                          <asp:Button ID="btnCancelTrip" runat="server" OnClick="btnCancelTrip_Click" Text="Cancel Trip" CssClass="btn btn-warning" />&nbsp;
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
        </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Trip No">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTripRefID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TripRefID") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Name">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCompanyName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CompanyName") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pickup Location">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPickupLocation" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PickupLocation") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**C# Code**

```html
protected void dtgViewDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.CommandName == "Assign")
    {
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridView grid = (GridView)sender;
        if (grid.ID == "dtgViewDetails")
        {
            Label lblTrip_ID = (Label)grid.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("lblTrip_ID");
            DropDownList ddlDriver = (DropDownList)grid.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("ddlDriver");
        }
    }
 }
```

But i get the by default of dropdownlist that zeroth index value.
please help me..
thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you mean you get the DDL at row index 0? Or do you mean you always get the DDLs first value? I'm guessing option one as you don't seem to be getting any value from the DDL in your code.

Comment: Also, make sure you are not rebinding your Gridviews before the RowCommand event fires. For example, OnLoad or OnInit. Set some breakpoints to see what event fires when and research the Page Life Cycle for ASP.net Web Forms.

Comment: Tested your snippet, it works. Did you wrap the binding of both the GridViews inside `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { //bind grid here }`

Comment: hi Jon P ... yes i always get the ddl's first value only......  And i bind the first grid view in my page lode and the second(Child) grid bind in first grid RowDataBound.  How can i get the real selected value of DDL.

Comment: Hai VDWWD .... I already use (!IsPostBack) and bind the first Grid inside this. And the second(Child) grid bind in first grid RowDataBound. If is it possible to bind child grid in (!IsPostBack) please give me a example because i don't know about that.

Comment: Things to check that could point you in the direction of the problem. Is `rowIndex` the expected row? Is the retrieved `ddlDrive` the control  you expect? Please show how you are actually attempting to retrieve the value, all you show at the moment is finding the control.